# How can I determine where the issue with my MultiDataTrigger is coming from?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I currently have a DataGrid being styled by DataTriggers. I've run into the issue that a MultiDataTrigger will not style the row when one condition is present - a condition that works fine in a DataTrigger.

This Works:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Error">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF88FF"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

This Works:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BgColor}" Value="{x:Null}">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF88FF"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

This does not work:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
   <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Error"/>
      <Condition Binding="{Binding BgColor}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
   </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF88FF"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

What would influence the MultiDataTrigger to not work?
There are multiple instances where both conditions should be met.

Comment: The `MultiDataTrigger` looks correct. Are you sure that _both_ conditions actually are ever met by _one_ binding source? Have you forced the expected condition by intentionally setting the properties to the required value?

Comment: @BionicCode Yes, I've forced the properties and I'm still unable to get them to respond in the desired way. As mentioned both DataTriggers work correctly on the same item; just not in the MultiDataTrigger.

Comment: I'm going to attempt to reproduce this issue on a clean project.

Comment: Look at the output pane for binding errors. If you need more detail, set PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High on each binding in turn, and you’ll get a lot more detail in the output pane.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it should work ,you can cross verify by adding dummy converter to your XAML and bind the "Type" and "BgColor" to it then you can check exact value